# Unexpected unsigned integer behavior

Tags: c

I encountered this unexpected output with the following code in which I was verifying the maximum values (represented in decimal form) of the unsigned forms of short and int types when all their bits were set to 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n1 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    unsigned short n2 = 0xFFFF;

    printf("\nMax int = %+d", n1);
    printf("\nMax short = %+d", n2);

   return 0;
}
```

The output I get is (compiled using the Visual Studio 2017 C/C++ Compiler):

```
Max int = -1
Max short = +65535
```

Along the lines of unsigned short, I was expecting the maximum value of the unsigned int to be +4294967295. Why isn't it so?

Comment: Seriously, check that your debugging technique is correct before deducing the language is crazy.

Comment: `%d` is for `int`, you're looking for `%u`. That said, the maximum unsigned is always `(unsigned)-1`.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. Anything is possible. Check your harddrive, it might have been wiped. Enable and fix to compiler warnings before asking!

Comment: What would have happened here if `sizeof(int)` was 16 (64-bit int) ?

Comment: @Bathsheba: One downvote reason is "does not show any research effort". Would you consider reading the `printf` man-page to find the correct conversion type specifier being expectable effort? I don't even ask about finding one of the 10000 dups here or simply enable compiler warnings, as every modern compiler/library will warn.

Comment: @cdarke: `sizeof(type)` does not say anything about the width of `type`. `sizeof(int) == 1` is perfectly valid. And even with `CHAR_BIT == 8`, `sizeof(uint64_t)` is `8`, not `16` (that value is not possible, actually).

Comment: @Olaf:  that wasn't what I meant, it was the effect of `unsigned int n1 = 0xFFFFFFFF;` on a 64-bit int that I was referring to.  The answers all used `-1` (which is correct for these purposes), which the OP did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `printf()`, your conversions in the format string **must** match the type of the arguments, otherwise the behavior is **undefined**. `%d` is for `int`.

Try this for the maximum values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Max unsigned int = %u\n", (unsigned)-1);
    printf("Max unsigned short = %hu\n", (unsigned short)-1);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Side notes:

- the maximum value of any unsigned type is `-1` cast to that type.
- Put newline at the *end* of your lines. Among other reasons, this flushes `stdout`s buffer with the default setting of *line buffered*.

Comment: Does (unsigned)-1 and (unsigned short)-1 usage correspond to casting?

Comment: "correspond"? writing the type in parantheses in front of the operand to cast *is* the cast operator in C...

Comment: My bad... failed to recognize -1 was being casted

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `%u` for the format specifier for an `unsigned` type.